# Printing the digits of an integer in correct order using recursion

Tags: c++

How to print the digits of an integer of unknown length, in its correct order, using a single recursive function??

```
int digit(int n)
{       
    if (n==0)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        cout << n%10 << endl;
        return digit(n/10);
    }
}
//the above function prints it in reverse
```

Comment: what code have you written so far?

Comment: std::cout << yourInteger; :) You should provide the code you wrote so far and what's your requirement (do you have to mimic printf/cout?)

Comment: Are you telling us some numbers have their digits in the incorrect order? :O

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum and is not a code-writing or debugging service. You are expected to do your own research and as a question only when you have tried to make your code work and failed. Even then you are expected to provide full background, including what you tried, why you think it didn't work, and what happened when it didn't work.

Comment: Why does `digit` have a return value?  And what does it signify?  (As for getting the right order, all you have to do is invert the order of the `cout` and the recursion.)

Comment: digit has a return value as it is a recursive function...
as for inverting the order of cout, how do i do that? That is the point of the entire post....

Comment: @XxXunderage But what does the return value signify.  (As for inverting the order between the output and the recursion: you use an editor.  Do you mean that you don't understand the concept of changing the order of two statements.)

Comment: Actually you don't use anywhere the return value. A recursive function is...recursive because it calls itself, return value isn't required for that (by the way...that code shouldn't even compile).

Comment: @XxXunderage Note that as written, your code has undefined behavior: you fall off the end of the function without returning a value if `n` is 0, and you then propagate this undefined return value down through the recursive calls.

Comment: @Adriano I don't see why it shouldn't compile---I think a compiler is required to compile it (although it will have undefined behavior if he ever calls the function).

Comment: @JamesKanze right about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work;

[**EDIT:** The code works for inputs i.e. +ve, 0, -ve integers; it prints the digits only, not a -ve sign]

```
void digit(int n) //no need to return a value
{   
    if (n < 0)
        n = -1*n;
    if (n/10 > 0) //no need have else blocks
    {
        //for the correct order, make the recursive call first
        digit(n/10);            
    }
    //print when you reach the most significant digit
    cout << n%10 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using return as I had been using int digit, not void digit.

Comment: You've been of great help.

Comment: You might want to move the output out of the test (and change the test to `n / 10 > 0`).  This will ensure at least one digit.  (And I wonder about converting each digit as an `int`.  I would assume that one of the goals would be to do the conversion yourself, outputting something like `"01234546789"[n % 10]`.

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly what do you mean. I've tested the above code and it's working for me. Are there any boundary cases you're talking about?

Comment: For the case `digit(0)` the solution prints nothing. Nor does it for any negative value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about, what step to take in a single function call and what to delegate to the next function call. Printing one digit seems to be a good candidate. Taking the least significant (right most) digit is quit easy: it's the remainder of dividing the integer by 10.

As you want to output the least significant digit at last, you have to delegate to your function first:

```
digit( n / 10 );
std::cout << n % 10;
```

Comment: And what about his return value?  Until he clarifies what his return value is supposed to mean, it's difficult to say what he should do.

Comment: I wrote the answer before he showed any code. I don't get any meaning from is description of the return value.